# Change TextInputLayout text color after entering text in edittext

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a floating edittext in my app

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_input_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_input_margin">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        style="@style/EditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/width_height_6"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
                        android:hint="@string/email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/password"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and its style

```
 <style name="EditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/margin_padding_3</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/margin_padding_2</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/margin_padding_3</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Now its current behavior is like when `Edittext` gets focused the label is floated to top and highlighted, Now i want to do like when user enters text in `Edittext` and removes focus the `TextInputLayout` color should be changed to a different color and keep that color until `Edittext` text removed.